# How to find a mongoId in an array of mongoIds outside a db call

Tags: node.js, mongoose, objectid

I'm aware its possible to find this out via a db call, but out of curiosity for instance in node If I had an array of mongoose document ids. How could I emulate an indexOf function against that array to determine if another mongoId is in it?

I only ask since doing a direct comparison of ids doesn't work and requires the use of `objectId.equals()' function. Is there a mongoose/mongoId function that does something similar to indexOf for ids?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you are not sure which is a string or which is an ObjectId in your comparisons then just convert everything to a "string". All objects have `.toString()`, even strings. And for array transformation just use `.map()`.

Example:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var objSchema = new Schema({

});

var Obj = mongoose.model('Obj',objSchema);


var arrayTest1 = [],
    arrayTest2 = [];

for ( x = 0; x < 10; x++ ) {
  var obj = new Obj();
  arrayTest1.push( obj.id );
  arrayTest2.push( obj.id.toString() );
}

var el1 = arrayTest1[4],
    el2 = arrayTest2[3];

[el1,el2].forEach(function(el) {
  console.log( el );
});

console.log( arrayTest1.indexOf(el1) );
console.log( arrayTest2.indexOf(el2) );


console.log( arrayTest1.map(function(el) {
  return el.toString()
}).indexOf(el1.toString()));
console.log( arrayTest2.map(function(el) {
  return el.toString()
}).indexOf(el2.toString()));
```

Both pairs of statement evaluate to their correct index matches. So the second form there is universal to the object type. ObjectId or sting on either side.